# Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 - Lock screen takes lot of time to unlock

Tags: 13.04, gnome, lock-screen

I have gnome-screensaver package installed for using Ctrl+Alt+L to lock the screen. Though locking the screen works fine, it takes a whole lot of time to unlock after entering my password at the prompt. The lock screen just freezes during the time (mouse is active).

Here are the log messages from `$HOME/.cache/gdm/session.log`

1. When screen is locked:

   ```
   (gnome-shell:2850): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Dropping signal ActiveSessionChanged of type (s) since the type from the expected interface is (o) 
   (above message repeated 5 times)

     JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: arguments[0] is null
     JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"arguments[0] is null"'
     JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autorunManager.js"'
     JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '133'
     JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"(null,[object _private_Gio_IOErrorEnum])@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
     ([object _private_Gio_DBusProxy],[object _private_Gio_SimpleAsyncResult])@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/overrides/Gio.js:86"'
   ```
2. When screen is unlocked:

   ```
   (gnome-shell:2850): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Dropping signal ActiveSessionChanged of type (s) since the type from the expected interface is (o)
   (above message repeated 4 times)

   JS LOG: loading default theme (Adwaita)

   (gnome-shell:2850): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Dropping signal ActiveSessionChanged of type (s) since the type from the expected interface is (o)
   (above message repeated 13 times)

   JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: arguments[0] is null
   JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"arguments[0] is null"'
   JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autorunManager.js"'
   JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '133'
   JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"(null,[object _private_Gio_IOErrorEnum])@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
   ([object _private_Gio_DBusProxy],[object _private_Gio_SimpleAsyncResult])@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/overrides/Gio.js:86"' 
   (above block repeated 4 times)
   ```

Are these related to the long delay/freeze in unlocking the screen? or is it caused by some other software etc.

Glad to provide any extra information in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Which display manager are you using. To know just run this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. On the list, the selected display manager will be your default. Reply..

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: ^^ Nope. Not yet. @Saurav I am using gdm (comes by default on Ubuntu-GNOME)

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should hit the bugtrackers ([launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver), [gnome project](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/)) and, if you don't find any matching your description, report your own.

Comment: Even I would like to know the answer. Happens to me on initial login.
Could this be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome2/+bug/151544)

Comment: Not able to reproduce in Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome remix. Can you provide the output of `debsums -s` and `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-common`

Answer (score 0):

@DavidFoerster: Yes it is a bug.

See here: [Launchpad Bug #515155](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/515155). You may also find a workaround there.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Tweak Tool if not already installed and the Gnome Shell extensions. The extensions are enabled in the Tweak Tool / Advanced Settings. The alternative status menu extension displays the shutdown menu. You can adjust it there.